# How to get the AuthenticationManager when using the AuthenticationManagerBuilder to add custom provider?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0 (leveraging Spring Security 5.0).  I'm trying to add a custom AuthenticationProvider to the AuthenticationManager in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter subclass.  If I override the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` method to supply my new provider, then I do not know how to retrieve the AuthenticationManager as a bean.

Ex:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

where `customAuthenticationProvider` implements `AuthenticationProvider`.

In the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-authenticationprovider), it seems to specify that the two are incompatible:

> 5.8.4 AuthenticationProvider You can define custom authentication by exposing a custom AuthenticationProvider as a bean. For example, the
>   following will customize authentication assuming that
>   SpringAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider:
>
> [Note] This is only used if the AuthenticationManagerBuilder has not
>   been populated

Indeed, if I try to retrieve the AuthenticationManager bean using:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

then the `configure()` method is never even called.

So how can I add my own custom provider to the default list of providers, and still be able to retrieve the AuthenticationManager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just override `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManagerBean()` method and annotate it with `@Bean` annotation

```
 @Bean
 @Override
 public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
     return super.authenticationManagerBean();
 }
```

And there is no Spring Boot 5.0, The latest release is Spring Boot 2.0. I believe you are talking about Spring Security 5.0.

Comment: I knew the answer was in front of my eyes somewhere, but just couldn't find it.  I have to say, I'm a little surprised that the just the method name makes such a difference.  I would have thought spring would have taken that possibility into account (ie: exposing the authentication by a different manner)